# scrolling issues in ionic modal

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using the following directive template for multiselect dropdown

```
    var template = '<div class="multiselect-parent">';
        template += '<button ng-click="toggleDropdown(settings.name)" type="button" class="" ng-class="settings.buttonClasses"><label>{{getButtonText()}}&nbsp;</label><span ng-class="{\'dd-fl-icon\' : filterIcon}" class="dd-dw-icon pull-right"><i class="ion-arrow-down-b"></i><i ng-show="filterIcon" class="ion-funnel"></i></span></button>';
        template += '<div class="dropdown" ng-style="{display: open ? \'block\' : \'none\'}">';
        template += '<div ng-show="settings.enableSearch"><div class="dropdown-header"><input type="text" class="dropdown-search" style="width: 100%;" ng-model="searchFilter" placeholder="{{texts.searchPlaceholder}}" /><i class="ion-ios-search-strong"></i></div></div>';
        template += '<ion-scroll ng-style="{height : settings.scrollable ? settings.scrollableHeight : \'auto\'}" direction="y"><ul class="dropdown-ul"><li ng-hide="!settings.showCheckAll || settings.selectionLimit > 0 || hideOnFilter || ddAllchecked || !(options| filter:searchFilter).length" ng-show="!ddAllchecked"><div class="checkbox"><label data-ng-click="selectAll(dropdownCheckAll);"><input class="checkboxInput" type="checkbox" ng-model="dropdownCheckAll" ng-checked="ddAllchecked" />&nbsp;{{texts.checkAll}}</label></div></li>';
        template += '<li ng-show="!(options| filter:searchFilter).length"><div class="checkbox">{{texts.noResult}}</div></li>';
        template += '<li ng-show="settings.showUncheckAll" ng-hide="!ddAllchecked || !(options| filter:searchFilter).length"><div class="checkbox"><label data-ng-click="selectAll(dropdownCheckAll);"><input class="checkboxInput" type="checkbox" ng-model="dropdownCheckAll" ng-checked="ddAllchecked" />&nbsp;{{texts.uncheckAll}}</label></div></li>';
        if (groups) {
            template += '<li ng-repeat-start="option in orderedItems | filter: searchFilter" ng-show="getPropertyForObject(option, settings.groupBy) !== getPropertyForObject(orderedItems[$index - 1], settings.groupBy)" role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">{{ getGroupTitle(getPropertyForObject(option, settings.groupBy)) }}</li>';
            template += '<li ng-repeat-end role="presentation">';
        } else {
                template += '<li role="presentation" ng-repeat="option in options | filter:searchFilter">';
        }

        template += '<a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" ng-click="setSelectedItem(getPropertyForObject(option,settings.idProp))">';

        if (checkboxes) {
            template += '<div class="checkbox"><label><input class="checkboxInput" type="checkbox" ng-click="checkboxClick($event, getPropertyForObject(option,settings.idProp))" ng-checked="isChecked(getPropertyForObject(option,settings.idProp))" /> {{getPropertyForObject(option, settings.displayProp)}}</label></div></a>';
        } else {
            template += '<span data-ng-class="{\'glyphicon glyphicon-ok\': isChecked(getPropertyForObject(option,settings.idProp))}"></span> {{getPropertyForObject(option, settings.displayProp)}}</a>';
        }

        template += '</li>';

        template += '<li class="divider" ng-show="settings.selectionLimit > 1"></li>';
        template += '<li role="presentation" ng-show="settings.selectionLimit > 1"><a role="menuitem">{{selectedModel.length}} {{texts.selectionOf}} {{settings.selectionLimit}} {{texts.selectionCount}}</a></li>';

        template += '</ul></ion-scroll>';
        template += '</div></div>';
```

When I use it in normal view then I am facing no issues but when I use it in ionic modal then I face scrolling issues that also only in android device.

Any help will be appreciated? Thank you

Comment: Can u put your code to http://play.ionic.io/ ?? I'd like to see your modal's template

Comment: sorry, can't do that coz bounded by T&Cs. Can't share app exclusively